# Driving UIImagePickerController from UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Here's my goal:
I'd like to show the UIImagePickerController from a TabBarController and once the photo is taken, I want the "Use" button to take me another view controller.

My problem:
I have MainCameraTabController which inherits from UIViewController and serves as the class that orchestrates the launching of UIImagePickerController and the picker's delegate. When the picker is finished, I try to launch another a different ViewController from MainCameraTabController but I get the error,

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:
```

If I put a timed delay between when the UIImagePickerController is dismissed and when I launch the next controller, it works okay but I'd like to do this more elegantly.

Is there a better way to structure my class inheritance so that I can have MainCameraTabController display the Picker and then a 2nd view controller?

```
// #
// # 1. Create the tab bar and add the MainCameraTabController:
// #
// tab1Controller and tab3Controller are also created
cameraTabController = [[MainCameraTabController alloc] init];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];                                                                                                      

NSArray *tabViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tab1Controller, 
                                            cameraTabController
                                            tab3Controller, nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = tabViewControllers;

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;


// #
// # 2. MainCameraTabController interface & implementation
// #

@interface MainCameraTabController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
}
- (void)showCamera;

@end

@implementation MainCameraTabController

// #
// # 3. Show the camera when the view loads
// #
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self startCameraController:self usingDelegate:self];
}

- (void)showNextController
{
    FollowupController *fc = [[FollowupController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil];

    //  THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    [self presentModalViewController:cameraPicker animated: YES];
}

- (BOOL)startCameraController:(UIViewController *)controller
                usingDelegate:(id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>)pickerDelegate 
{

    UIImagePickerController *cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    // configure the cameraPicker

    // #
    // # Apple's doc specifies that UIImagePickerController must be launched with   
    // # presentModalViewController
    // #

    [controller presentModalViewController:cameraPicker animated: YES];    
}

// UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method called when photo taking is finished
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    // work to handle the photo

    // Dismiss the picker
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [picker release];    

    [self showNextController];
}

@end
```

And on a related note, I checked to see what the picker's parentViewController is when

imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

is invoked and the parent is not MainCameraTabController but instead UITabBarController. Not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the animation when dismissing the view, you need delay for the animation to finish before it can execute the next animation. You can solve this by setting the `animated` to `NO`. This will cut the animation and execute the next one immediately.

For the views, i had the similar experience, what i did was to switch the sequence of the views. I launched the view that i want to show after the picker first, in the `viewDidload` method, i created and display the picker so after the picker is dismissed, it will show the view that i want. If you want to make them look natural you could always play with the `hidden` property of the view to smoothen the flow.